# GridPane col/row coordinate without node

Tags: javafx, drag-and-drop, gridpane

I'm trying to figure out where the mouse is, in terms of a GridPane's column and row. I know the mouse position, so I could presumably figure it out from that, if I knew each cell's width and height (which I don't see an easy way to figure out) but most of the code I've seen seems to presume the mouse is over a node inside the GridPane:

```
        Node node = (Node) event.getTarget();
        int row = GridPane.getRowIndex(node);
        int column = GridPane.getColumnIndex(node);
```

But I actually don't have anything *inside* my GridPane, so I just get the whole GridPane. Now, I suppose I could add nodes for each of the cells, but this seems inefficient. (The idea is that the user is placing the nodes in a grid, so the grid starts out empty.)

Edit: To clarify, I basically want to do what SceneBuilder does when you place a GridPane down and then drag a component over it. The cell you're hovering over is highlighted and then (if you drop the component) it gets added to that cell. So I know it's possible (and also not outlandish as a concept).

Any thoughts?

Comment: why, what do want to achieve? the "grid" is just a mental image of the layout, nothing real

Comment: If you want to respond to mouse events, you should have a node on which those events happen. Create e.g. a blank pane for that purpose if you need.

Comment: @kleopatra The image isn't just mental: Think of what I want to do like SceneBuilder. Actually exactly like SceneBuilder. When you drag a button over a grid cell, that cell indicates and the button goes in that cell. That's exactly what I have in mind.

Comment: For further clarification: I don't want to create N blank nodes just so I can drop something on them. Maybe there's a better object than a GridPane for it, but I want to do exactly what SceneBuilder does.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't exactly answer my question but it's useful for me short term and it might be useful for others. It works *only* when the cells are uniform across the dimension being queried (i.e., all the same width/height).

```
 public int getCoord(double width, double coord, int numberOfSections) {
        long dim = Math.round(width / numberOfSections);
        long border = dim;
        int val = 0;
        while(coord > border) {
            border += dim;
            val++;
        }
        return val;
    }
```

Lacking a way to directly iterate over the current state of rows and columns, I think the full solution requires an analysis of children (if there are any) and the row and column constraints.